# Weld 1.1 + Solder causing unsatisfied dependencies?

Tags: cdi, weld, deltaspike, weld2

I was experiencing weird occurences of "WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies".

By all rules and docs, the dependency should be resolved. It was normal `@Produces` method and `@Inject` in some other bean.

```
@Produces @ApplicationScoped public Properties getEntityManagerFactoryProperties(){
    ...
}

@Inject
private Properties emfProperties;
```

Now I tried to upgrade from Weld 1.1.13 to 2.0.1, and started getting "WELD-001332 BeanManager method getBeans() is not available during application initialization", which is described in [SOLDER-339](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SOLDER-339).

Is it possible that solder is the culprit of the weird unsatisfied dependencies?

Comment: if you could post the full exception, that would help.  i would recommend new projects to use deltaspike instead of solder, just for current maintainability.  solder is not compatible with weld 2/cdi 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Probably. We haven't been doing anything with Solder for over a year. Is there something you need from it which isn't in DeltaSpike?

EDIT: Yes, Solder does not work with Weld 2.0, there hasn't been any serious work on it for over a year. Efforts from the Seam team are being put into DeltaSpike. The vast majority of what you were using in Solder is now in DeltaSpike Core.

Comment: No idea, haven't looked at DeltaSpike yet. I guess time to.